# Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently I am upgrading a project from angular 2 to angular 6. Stumble upon some service code which is running in the previous version but not in newer

```
    protected static createResourceFromData<T>(type : { new(): T ;}, data : Object) : T {
        var result = new type();
        for (var key in result) {
            if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                continue;
            }//if (key != 'id' && result[key] !== null && typeof data[key] == 'undefined') this line has been here previous replace for making runable
            if (key != 'id' && result[key] !== null ) {
                throw 'Resource parsing error - key "' + key + '" not found';
            }
            result[key] = data[key];
        }
        if (data['createdAt']) {
            result['createdAt'] = data['createdAt'];
        }
        if (data['updatedAt']) {
            result['updatedAt'] = data['updatedAt'];
        }
        if (data['deletedAt']) {
            result['deletedAt'] = data['deletedAt'];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

getting the error given below:

> Type 'Object[Extract]' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract]'.
>   Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>   The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead

As I am new to both Angular and Typescript, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use a more-precise type than `Object`.

Comment: It looks like `data` should at least contain all the key/value types that `result` does, so probably `data` should be annotated as `T` instead of `Object`

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments - the problem is in `data` type, which is `Object` in your example. There can be two cases:

1) When `data` has the same type as `T`

```
    protected static createResourceFromData<T>(
        myType: { new(): T; },
        data: T 
    ): T {
        var result =
```

2) When `data` object keys extend from keys of `T`:

```
    protected static createResourceFromData<T>(
        myType: { new(): T; },
        data: { [key in Extract<keyof T, string>]: T[key]; } 
    ): T {
        var result = new myType();
        ...
```

*Notice* that I've renamed `type` argument to `myType` (you have to rename it and choose appropriate name), to avoid confusions with TS `type` keyword.